# Python that takes a string and displays that string centered within line_width characters

Tags: python-3.x, string

Hello guys  for example;

```
def right_justify( in_str):   
    print("+" * 5,in_str.rjust(11),"+"*5)

right_justify("Hello")
```

my function prints out;

and why prints out like this?

```
+++++       Hello +++++
```

and ı wannt to print this;

```
+++++Hello+++++
```

How can ı make this to make it look more beautiful? :)

Comment: To be fairly honest, this looks like homework to me.

Comment: Actually ıt's  not a homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `f`string or `str.format`

**Ex:**

```
def right_justify( in_str):
    val = "+"*5
    print("{}{}{}".format(val, in_str, val))
    print(f"{val}{in_str}{val}")
right_justify("Hello")
```

**Output:**

```
+++++Hello+++++
+++++Hello+++++
```

Answer (score 2):

This is literally what your code outputs:

```
('+++++', '      Hello', '+++++')
```

And that's because of the call to `rjust(11)` which does exactly what the name implies - it justifies the string 11 characters to the right. Remove that method and your output will be exactly what you want it to be.

Comment: Thank you now ı understand it :)